# New gplots update in R cannot find function distfun in heatmap.2

Tags: r

I have a bit of R-code to make a heatmap from a correlation matrix, which worked the last time I used it (prior to the 2013 Oct 17 update of gplots; after updating to R Version 3.0.2). This makes me think that something changed in the most recent gplots update, but I can not figure out what.

What used to present a nice plot now gives me this error:

> " Error in hclustfun(distfun(x)) : could not find function "distfun" "

and won't plot anything. Below is the code to reproduce the plot (heavily commented as I was using it to teach an undergrad how to use heatmaps for a project). I tried adding the last line to explicitly set the functions, but it didn't help resolve the problem.

EDIT: I changed the last line of code to read: 
   ,distfun =function(c) {as.dist(1-c,upper=FALSE)}, hclustfun=hclust)
and it worked. When I used just "dist=as.dist" I got a plot, but it wasn't sorted right, and several of the dendrogram branches didn't connect to the tree. Not sure what happened, or why this is working, but it appears to be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

```
library(gplots)
set.seed(12345)

randData <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(600),ncol=6))

randDataCorrs <- randData+(rnorm(600))
names(randDataCorrs) <- paste(names(randDataCorrs),"_c",sep="")
randDataExtra <- cbind(randData,randDataCorrs)

randDataExtraMatrix <- cor(randDataExtra)


heatmap.2(randDataExtraMatrix, # sets the correlation matrix to use
          symm=TRUE, #tells whether it is symmetrical or not
          main= "Correlation matrix\nof Random Data Cor", # Names plot
          xlab= "x groups",ylab="", # Sets the x and y labels
          scale="none", # Tells it not to scale the data
          col=redblue(256),# Sets the colors (can be manual, see below) 
          trace="none", # tells it not to add a trace
          symkey=TRUE,symbreaks=TRUE, # Tells it to keep things symmetric around 0
          density.info = "none"#) # can be "histogram" if you want a hist of your corr values here
          #,distfun=dist, hclustfun=hclust)
          ,distfun =function(c) {as.dist(1-c,upper=FALSE)}, hclustfun=hclust) # new last line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error, then I noticed that I had made a variable called dist, which is the default call for `distfun= dist`. **I renamed the variable and then everything ran fine.** You likely made the same error, as your new code is working since you have altered the default call of `distfun`.